# Как правильно создать проект intellij idea интегрированную в GitHub?

Tags: git, gradle

Запарился конкретно. Создаю проект gradle, не могу клонировать на репозиторий GitHub, клонирую репу с GitHub, получаю ветки master & main на разных уровнях в папке. Объединить не получается.
Друзья! Научите пожалуйста, как правильно создать проект, с поддержкой gradle & GitHub одновременно??

1. создаю репозиторий GitHub
2. Создаю проект под управлением gradle.
3. в Git Bash проваливаюсь в локальный репозиторий,
4. Выполняю git clone.
   Получаю Head Master, хотя клонировал main. В результате, проект в проекте. При выполнении Push, ветка main копируется, master нет.

Спасибо.

---

Я всю переписку на этот вопрос перенес на бумагу. Огромное человеческое спасибо ВСЕМ!!!

Comment: github и gradle немного перпендикулярные штуки. Для Github (пока не начнете прикручивать CI/CD), gradle - это просто файлы. Попробуйте переформулировать свой вопрос.

Comment: Мне бы порядок действий при создании проекта. Я указываю при создании проекта gradle, а как скрестить с githab не знаю.

Comment: Чтоб можно было помочь как-то, покажите, какие команды вы пробуете выполнять и что получается в результате. Пока что из описания понятно только, что не получается достичь того, что вы хотите. Нужно объяснить что вы имеете ввиду, когда пишете "клонирую на репозиторий", "клонирую с github", "получаю на разных уровнях".

Comment: 1. создаю репозиторий Githab 2. Создаю проект под управлением gradle.  3. в Git Bash проваливаюсь в локальный репозиторий, 4. Выполняю git clone. Получаю Head Master, хотя клонировал main. В результате, проект в проекте. При выполнении Push, ветка main копируется, master нет.

Comment: Это нужно дописать в вопрос кнопкой "править". Комментарии не для этого.

Comment: Извините, за столь не ясные вопросы. Просто я еще учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Когда Вы на 4 этапе делаете clone, то да, Вы клонируете проект внутрь своего. Что делать? не клонируйте, Вы же только создаете проект.

Переделам 4 пункт. Вначале нужно инициализировать проект `git init .`

Потом добавляем origin, выглядит это где то так и github эти команды и предлагает

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

Но теперь у нас есть проблема. Есть проект на сервере и у Вас локальный. Поэтому делаем git pull и мержим/ребейзим по необходимости.

И теперь можно спокойно сделать git push и проект улетит на github.

По поводу master/main. Раньше в гит было по стандарту использовать master для самой первой ветки. Но потом некоторые люди решили, что это название немного ущемляет их и пошло движение убрать такие имена везде где можно. И было решено заменить на main. Github выбрал промежуточную стратегию - они по умолчанию для новых проектов предлагают main. А старым предлагают переименовать (что иногда приводит к куче разных проблем:) ).

Но вообще то в IDEA есть кнопка "share", с помощью которой можно "опубликовать свой проект - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html#jump_to_github_version и не нужно на гитхабе ничего создавать. А вот [тут](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/11/sharing-your-project-on-github/) все с картинками и красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два принципиальных пути, как начать работать с репозиторием в github.

### Создание c нуля

Тут последовательность действий такая:

1. создаем репозиторий на github
2. клонируем его на локальный компьютер
3. добавляем в склонированную директорию файлы проекта

Последовательность описана в README после создания репозитория или [здесь](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository#cloning-an-empty-repository).

### Cоздание из существующих исходников

В этом случае последовательность такая:

1. создаем репозиторий на github
2. инициализируем репозиторий в локальной папке с исходниками
3. добавляем репозиторий github как remote репозиторий к созданному локально
4. делаем `git pull`

Детально, со всеми командами, последовательность описана [тут](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Фух.. Разобрался... Удалил репозиторий из GitHab, создал проект под управлением gradle, дальше VCC, import into version control, share project on github. Создался репозиторий, встал под контроль Git на Head Master. Получил все что хотел.
Спасибо всем за не безразличие к моей проблеме.